# Создание нескольких picturebox

Tags: c#

Разрабатываю игру flappy bird, столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу прорисовать трубы(PictureBox). Написал код для прорисовки труб, создал массивы, однако прорисовываются лишь 2-е трубы. Кто может сказать, как исправить это?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms; 

namespace FlappyBird
{
public partial class GameForm : Form
{
    Graphics g;
    bool jumping = false;//прыжок
    int pipeSpeed = 5;//скорость передвижения блоков
    int gravity = 5;//скорость прыжка
    int Inscore = 0;
    int pr = 77;//расстояние между верхним и нижним блоком
    int range = 157;//расстояние между нижними или верхними блоками
    int stp = 237;
    Random r = new Random();
    PictureBox[] pipe = new PictureBox[1000];
    public GameForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Draw()
    {
        Refresh();
        g = CreateGraphics();
        int i = 1, j = 1;
        for (; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (; j < 2; j++)
            {
                //прорисовка труб снизу
                PictureBox pBot = new PictureBox();
                pBot.Image = pipeBottom.Image;
                pBot.Location = new Point(pipeBottom.Location.X + range, 311);
                pBot.Size = new Size(53, r.Next(165, 405));
                pBot.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                pipe[i] = pBot;
                Controls.Add(pipe[i]);
                //прорисовка труб сверху
                PictureBox pUp = new PictureBox();
                pUp.Image = pipeUp.Image;
                pUp.Location = new Point(pipeUp.Location.X + range, 0);
                pUp.Size = new Size(53, this.ClientSize.Height - (pr + pBot.Height));
                pUp.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                pipe[j] = pUp;
                Controls.Add(pipe[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: поставьте точку останова, и посмотрите координаты в каждой итерации...вы сами увидите тогда что и где именно не так.

Comment: и еще...может вам стоит написать проект в `unity`?

Comment: Зачем вызывается Dispose?

Comment: Я уже его удалил